# UISearchBar Above Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

All the applications I have ever seen, that use UINavigationBars, have the UINavigationBar right at the top of the app. If you want to use a UISearchBar then it's usually in the 'header' of the UITableView such as this...

[addressbook http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d715f77301.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/d715f77301.png)

What I would like to do is to put a UISearchBar object above/outside of the UINavigationBar/Controller, but i've been having some problems doing this.

[genericnibfile http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f6025a02e5.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f6025a02e5.png)

Firstly, is what I want to achieve even possible? What would the easiest way to do this be?

Starting with the navigation based application seems to make the navigationbar/view un-resizeable!

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I re-thought my layout and design, and then realised I didn't have to include the search bar in the table view header. The table UISearchBar sits above the UITableView and doesn't scroll. Winner winner chicken dinner.

Comment: Feel free to delete this question, it's a pretty pointless one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the search bar and the navigation view to a root view/controller, and then manage the flow from there. Might end up in a complex flow though, so I'd only do this if that change in layout is really that important to you.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i'm going for at the moment. I have two views. One which exclusively holds the search bar, and then one that holds the navigation view/controller... fingers crossed.